# Trouble with submitting Contact Form plugin contact via AJAX

Tags: plugin-contactform

I’m having trouble getting Contact Form to work when posting through AJAX.

Form:

```
{% macro errorList(errors) %}
    {% if errors %}
        <ul class="errors">
            {% for error in errors %}
                <li>{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}

{% from _self import errorList %}

<div id="my-form" class="form">

    <form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    {{ getCsrfInput() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="contactForm/sendMessage">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="contact/thanks">

      <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
          <div class="medium-6 cell">
            <h3><label for="fromEmail">Your Email</label></h3>
                <input id="fromEmail" type="email" name="fromEmail" value="{% if message is defined %}{{ message.fromEmail }}{% endif %}">
                {{ message is defined and message ? errorList(message.getErrors('fromEmail')) }}
          </div>
          <div class="medium-12 cell">
            <h3><label for="message">Message</label></h3>
                <textarea rows="10" cols="40" id="message" name="message">{% if message is defined %}{{ message.message }}{% endif %}</textarea>
                {{ message is defined and message ? errorList(message.getErrors('message')) }}

                <input type="submit" value="Send">
          </div>
          <div id="thanks" style="opacity:0">THANKS</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#my-form').submit(function(ev) {
    // Prevent the form from actually submitting
    ev.preventDefault();

    // Get the post data
    var data = $(this).serialize();

    // Send it to the server
    $.post('/', data, function(response) {
        if (response.success) {
            $('#thanks').fadeIn();
        } else {
            // response.error will be an object containing any validation errors that occurred, indexed by field name
            // e.g. response.error.fromName => ['From Name is required']
            alert('An error occurred. Please try again.');
        }
    });
});
```

In this case the response is not a success so the alert is triggered.

Out of interest I console logged the response in the else block and it’s all the HTML on the page. And then I thought, why don’t I console log the data variable right after it’s declared and - same thing - it’s all the HTML on the page.

Anybody got any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your html

```
<div id="my-form" class="form">
```

And This is your js event handler

```
$('#my-form').submit(function(ev) {
```

So `$(this)` is actually a `<div>` container element and `$(this).serialize()` is null so you'll send no data. You should add a id to your form

```
<form method="post" action="" id="myForm" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

and send the form data instead of a div data.

```
var data = $("#myForm").serialize();
```

I reproduced it, and it worked - even though I would prefer sending an actual object instead of a serialized form, but that's only subjective

Comment: Also remove the `id="my-form"` from the div! By the way, the reason you were getting a full html page response was because craft didn't know where to route the request due to the form data missing, so it displayed an error page (the html you received). A good next step would have been to check the request headers to see what was being posted to where.

Comment: Thanks, all. I'm a bit ashamed that I didn't pick up on this and deeply appreciate your assistance!